# scipy.optimize.linprog not working for me: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-programming

I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.linprog and it's not working for me in a simple case.  I must be doing something wrong -- help me out to find it please.

Here are the inputs and the expected solution and a test that the expected solution is feasible

```
import numpy, scipy.optimize
print "A", A_ub
print "b", b_ub
print "c", c
print "x_expected", x_expected
print "expected optimum", numpy.dot(c, x_expected)
print "feasibility test", numpy.dot(A_ub, x_expected) <= b_ub
```

This prints

```
A [[-1. -0.  0.  1.]
   [-0. -1.  1.  1.]
   [-1. -0. -0. -1.]
   [-0. -1. -1. -1.]]
b [ 2.  1. -2. -1.]
c [ 1.  1.  0.  0.]
x_expected [ 0  0 -1  2]
expected optimum 0.0
feasibility test [ True  True  True  True]
```

When I call linprog I get a feasible solution, but it seems to not be as optimal as the one I expected above.

```
r = scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub, b_ub)
x_derived = r.x
print "x_derived", x_derived
print "derived optimum", numpy.dot(c, x_derived)
print "derived feasibility", numpy.dot(A_ub, x_derived) <= b_ub
```

This prints

```
x_derived [ 1.  0.  0.  1.]
derived optimum 1.0
derived feasibility [ True  True  True  True]
```

Is there something wrong in my reasoning that I should be getting the expected solution (or a better one if there is one) instead of the one I get?  If I'm not wrong, how do I make linprog get it for me?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to maximize or minimize here?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize numpy.dot(c, x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linprog by default assumes usual linear programming lower bound `x >= 0`, which your "expected" solution does not satisfy. See the `bounds` keyword argument to change the bounds.